# Close polygon on ggmap (stat_contour)

Tags: r, plot, contour, ggmap

I have recently started coding with R, so far it has been quite a journey with several obstacles on the road. Most of them I have been able to solve by searching the internet. However, now I am encountering a problem I am unable to fix. I found a sort of similair thread on stackoverflow, ([How to fill in the contour fully using stat_contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469829/how-to-fill-in-the-contour-fully-using-stat-contour)), nevertheless it does not work in my situation, ggmap + ggplot seem unable to work together.

So, the problem is the following. I am studying whether the red light district in Amsterdam has an effect on local businesses. I do this by creating plot that shows business density in the city centre of Amsterdam. I have used this code to make it:

```
# Background map
geo <- geocode("Amsterdam", source="google")
lon <- geo$lon - .000
lat <- geo$lat + .000
map <- get_map(c(lon = lon, lat = lat), zoom=14,maptype = "satellite", color="color")

p <- ggmap(map) + theme(legend.position = c(1, 1), legend.justification = c(1,1)) + 
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")

# Map boundaries
#xmin = 4.86774509503174
#xmax = 4.92267673565674
#ymin = 52.3534171572766
#ymax = 52.386956071714

# RLD Map (so it can be read by ggplot2)
rldmap <- fortify(rld)
rld2map <- fortify(rld2)
natmap <- fortify(nat)

# Ticks
mid <- 250
mi <- 0
ma <- 500
r <- (ma-mi)/5
breaks = seq(mi,ma,r)

# Density
ncells <- 150

dens2000 <- kde2d(bedrijven2000$LONG, bedrijven2000$LAT, n = ncells)
densdf2000 <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = dens2000$x, y = dens2000$y), z = as.vector(dens2000$z))

densmap2000 <- p + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), data = coords2000, alpha = .5, size = 1) + 
  stat_contour(aes(x,y,z=z,fill = ..level..), data=densdf2000,geom="polygon", alpha=.3, inherit.aes = F) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(name="density", breaks = breaks, colours=rev(brewer.pal(7,"Spectral"))) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill='grey', size=.2,color='green', data=rldmap, alpha=0) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill='grey', size=.2,color='green', data=rld2map, alpha=0) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill='grey', size=.2,color='green', data=natmap, alpha=0) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), data = coords,color = 'yellow',alpha = 1, size = 1, shape=10) +
  annotate('text', x=4.892, y=52.374, label = "Amsterdam", col="white") +
  ggtitle("Business Density in Amsterdam year=2000")

plot(densmap2000)
```

Using this code provides the following output:
[output density plot Amsterdam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffUSK.png)

The problem here is that the lines of the polygons that show the density stop when they are close to the border of the plot, this gives a disturbing image.

Therefore my question is, how can I make the polygons forget about the borders of the graph and make them continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to answer the question myself in the end, thanks to this thread: [Truncated Density Polygons with ggmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485752/truncated-density-polygons-with-ggmap?rq=1)

the answer lies in two parts:

## 1, edit extend and maprange in background map

ggmap(map, extent="normal", maprange=FALSE)

## 2, edit in code for plot, add:

coord_cartesian(xlim=c(min(4.86774509503174),max(4.92267673565674)),
ylim=c(min(52.3534171572766),max(52.386956071714))) +